# Why is the link to 'proceed to checkout' a button type?

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, checkout

On the cart page ("/checkout/cart"), the link to "proceed to checkout" is a  with an onclick = window.location that sets the next page. Why is this?

More specifically, is there any risk introduced if I change this to an anchor tag with href = to the getCheckouturl?

This is probably common knowledge, but I could not find insight anywhere else.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have enough information to accept an answer yet - perhaps you have discovered something you'd like to add as a self-answer? Either way, please edit your question with additional details or accept an answer so that we can close this out. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There may be a canonical answer, but my best guess is for the following reasons:

- **Semantics**. The button is displayed as a clickable button, therefore the logical HTML element to use is a button.
- **Button 'disabling' becomes possible**. By using a button type when the button is disabled (`disabled="disabled"` attribute), the onclick will not fire. This makes it possible to prevent checkout if some condition has not been satisfied. [See an example fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4MLEx/).
- **Javascript is required by Magento** in order for the site to function - disable Javascript and you will see a warning from a `noscript` tag. Providing a button which will only redirect if JS enabled effectively prevents customers from entering the checkout without the ability to proceed.

Is there any risk in using an anchor tag? Not at all. Make sure that you generate the href, however, with the `getCheckoutUrl` method.